# How to compare rows of specific columns of two dataframes and in the event of equalness replace with them with specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare the all rows of one column of one data frame (df1) with all rows of one column of another data frame (df2). If the values are equal then the value of the cell of df2 shall be replaced by the value of the cell next to the compared cell of df1.

So for example:

I got the following data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'VALUES': [4, 6, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': [7, 8, 9, 10], 'VALUES': [4, 6, 6, 7]})
```

And the end result should look like this:

```
print(df2)


| NAME | VALUES   |
| ---- | -------- |
| 7    | 1        |
| 8    | 2        |
| 9    | 2        |
| 10   | 3        |
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'VALUES': [4, 6, 7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': [7, 8, 9, 10], 'VALUES': [4, 6, 6, 7]})
df_out = df2.merge(df1,on=['VALUES'],how='left')
df_out['VALUES'] = df_out['ID']
df_out[['NAME','VALUES']]
```

Please try this ,
it gives me below result

[image]

Comment: i confirm this works.  good work.